# Why is my /etc/network/interfaces not connecting to my WPA wireless network?

Tags: wireless, networking, server

I have two identical desktops running Ubuntu server 14.04. During the install process I only selected Ubuntu server, no other packages.

**Desktop #1)** This was my first linux build, and so fumbled around quite a bit until I figured it out. I configured the WPA_Supplicant.conf file utilizing the wpa_passphrase program, can can connect fine using wpa_supplicant. I can then get an ip using dhclient, or assign a static address in wpa_supplicant.conf... I also successfully configured the /etc/network/interfaces file .. first to connect via DHCP, then changed it to connect to a static IP. So.. for desktop #1 it works perfect.. connecting to my wireless network via WPA_supplicant manually, or automatically utilizing /etc/network/interfaces on boot.

**Desktop #2)** This is the problem machine. It is the same model, and same wireless card. I have successfully created the WPA_Supplicant.conf file, and can connect manually by running wpa_supplicant, then of course get an address via dhclient. It works great!!!! However, for the life of me, I can't connect automatically on logon with /etc/network/interfaces. It just doesn't connect! I can't find a single difference between the two machines!

Perhaps I inadvertently changed something on desktop #1 in my banging around to make it connect on logon?

**Here is my wpa_supplicant.conf:**

```
network={
ssid="myssid"
#### #psd="mypasscode"
psk=my-very-long-64char-passcode
}
```

**here is my /etc/network/interfaces:**

```
#### #The loopback network interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#### #The primary network interface
auto lo
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-essid myssid
wpa-psk my-very-long-64char-passcode
```

note: I have tried the wpa-psk as clear text, as well as 64bit.. either seems to work in desktop 1, neither seem to make a difference in desktop 2.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Oh to connect manually I simple run...

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo lshw -C network
sudo iwlist scan
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient wlan0
```

- **sudo lshw -C network** -  to confirm it is enabled
- **sudo iwlist scan** - to confirm it can scan
- **sudo wpa_supplicant** - to connect
- **dhclient wlan0** -  to get IP

this works great on both desktops.. it's just that I can't get desktop #2 to auto connect on logon!!!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

In /etc/network/interfaces, the declaration wpa-psk expects the password in clear text, not a 64-bit scrambled version. I suggest you amend your file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-essid myssid
wpa-psk mypasscode
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

The '-v' for verbose should produce some output indicating what's happening behind the scenes.

NOTE: "auto *lo* iface wlan0 inet dhcp" is incorrect. See my suggestion above.

Comment: Thanks.. I changed it back to clear text.. same thing. :(

Comment: Meaning what? Meaning it won't connect at all or it won't connect on boot?

Comment: Hi chili555 - sorry.. fist, my bad.. typo on auto lo.. my interfaces file is actually auto wlan0.. so that's not it. :(

Comment: As for a clearer definition of the symptoms (apologies).. it will not connect on logon. I can still connect manually, but not on logon. Interestingly, I have to clear out the interfaces file (comment out the lines) in order to connect manually. Otherwise, if I boot with the interfaces file (and it fails) I can't connect manually. I HAVE to log on without the system attempting to connect with interfaces in order to be able to connect manually.

Comment: Is Network Manager running? ps aux | grep -i network If so, it probably needs to be purged.

Comment: Hi All.. so, thank you for your assistance. I actually rebuilt the server. I really struggeled through this though as I wanted to understand WHY it was not working. At the end of the day I was using the "find" command with -exec rm.. and ended up deleting some files off of my home directory. So.. I just rebuilt.

Comment: .... continuing.. So after I rebuilt, I just edited the interfaces file and it worked right away.. so not sure what I did to break it.?? Anyway, thanks for all feedback and help!!!

Comment: .. since this is not technically answered.. can someone advise as to how to close this open question?

Comment: Not answered? Didn't the answer I gave work?

Comment: Hi chili555 - thank you for posting that. As I mentioned.. I actually deleted some files on my home directory by mistake.. so I just rebuilt the server. After rebuild I went directly in and edited the interfaces file and it worked fine. .. so not sure what the problem was. :(